# Message under Kafka topic is also called log?

Tags: apache-kafka

Message under Kafka topic is also called log?

log partitions = topic message partitions?

```
# The default number of log partitions per topic. More partitions allow greater
# parallelism for consumption, but this will also result in more files across
# the brokers.
num.partitions=1
```

Comment: yes, log=message. in fact, the property that defines where the messages are stored is called log.dirs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Kafka world, the "log" term refers to the messages stored by the broker itself. I can understand that sometimes it can drive to confusion but it's not related to the "logging" (about showing the status of the broker for example).