# Kafka Topic vs. Kafka Log - What is the difference between these two?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-topic

I often get to hear, read and see in a lot of tutorials, text guides or videos, that in the realm of Apache Kafka:

> *topics are just logs.*

I understand, that when we're mentioning *logs* in Kafka, we're not talking about logging systems (like Slf4j or etc.), and I also understand, that Kafka log is a name for an ordered collection of events (and topic is also that, as far as I know).

In the `KAFKA_HOME\config\server.properties` file, I even see this:

```
# A comma separated list of directories under which to store log files
log.dirs=C:/tmp/kafka-logs
```

But I still struggle to clearly differentiate Kafka topics and Kafka logs and understand what is the difference between those two.

If there are two names, there should be some differences.. or it's absolutely interchangeably terms?

P.S. I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54900938/1553537) and it doesn't really help.

Comment: I would say "topic" refers the concept of a queue that can have multiple subscribers. And in Kafka, this is implemented with a "log". So in Kafka, the two terms can be used quite interchangeably.

Comment: So, do I get it correct, that *topic* is a Kafka abstraction, that depicts some thing that producer can write in and consumer can read from.. however, the way how it's actually implemented, on a file level, is just log, i.e. Each Kafka topic (an abstract concept) is implemented by log file (a physical thing). Am I somewhat correct?

Comment: Yes, although a single Kafka topic can also be comprised of multiple logs (partitions).

Comment: On disk, topics are broken first into partition directories, then actual log files called segments

Answer (score 1):

A "log" in programming - and it is not narrowed to Kafka only - is an immutable somehow ordered sequence of events (rather than a collection as you stated - which lacks ordering and generally open for mutations).

So, a "transaction log" is an ordered sequence of transactions, which, once commited, can't be removed. On practice, however, there must exist an internal mechanism how to eventually wipe out longly outdated data otherwise the memory overflow is a question of time. In Kafka the "log compaction" services this purpose.

While Kafka's topics are specific to it. These are just named pieces, which you can address within a Kafka cluster, like `foo.bar` is a perfectly fine name for a  topic. It would be a logical name of the physical "partitions" of which this topic is built up and which actually store the (log) data at a disk.

Comment: I know what is a log.. thanks. :) So, it's just a conceptual comparison to the nature of logs? It's just conceptually compared to logs, because they have order, write-only and retention nature in files? (P. S. I was missing the word "ordered" before collection, and I've added it. Thanks).

Comment: Kafka is a distributed log in essence. So it's not just a comparison, it is the primary purpose of the whole thing. Hence term "Kafka topic" actually could be taken as a "a set of partitions each being a log [in the sense I defined it]".

Comment: So, again - then Topic is just a Kafka term (an abstract concept) and it's, under the hood, implemented as just log files. Is this correct?

Comment: Yeah, logs (called "Kafka partitions" officially) plus a specified distribution algorithm to spread data among them.